# Why is my answer showing as Infinity?

Tags: java, double, percentage

I am sort-of new to this so bear with me.

I am creating a program that allows the user to enter in the scores of a piece of coursework and an exam score and then total grade will be calculated. The values entered have to be between 1 and 10. The coursework is work 40% and the exam is worth 60%. The values 1-10 have to be converted into percentages and this is where I believe the infinity error is occurring.

This is my code (there will be 'if' and 'else' statements later in the code but I think I'll be ok with that. Also ignore Final Classification at the bottom):

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Question3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Coursework, Exam;

        Coursework = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter coursework score out of 10:");
        Exam = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter exam score out of 10");

        double CourseworkDoub, ExamDoub, CourseworkPerc, ExamPerc, FinalMark;

        CourseworkDoub = Double.parseDouble(Coursework);
        CourseworkPerc = (CourseworkDoub / 0.25);

        ExamDoub = Double.parseDouble(Exam);
        ExamPerc = (ExamDoub / (10 / 60));

        FinalMark = (CourseworkPerc + ExamPerc);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Final mark: " + FinalMark + "\nFinal classification is a ", "Result", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

    }

}
```

`CourseworkPerc` and `ExamPerc` seem to be the problem. I want to be able to show the percentage to 2 decimal places. For example, 5 out of 10 in the coursework (worth 40%) = 20.00%  and 5 out of 10 in the exam (worth 60%) = 30.00%  therefore the overall grade is 50.00%

Hopefully this makes sense. Appreciate any advice given. Thanks

Comment: Side note: `ExamDoub / (10 / 60) = ExamDoub / (1 / 6) = ExamDoub * 6`. Don't do unnecessary math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's due to the integer division in this line:

```
ExamPerc = (ExamDoub / (10 / 60));
```

`10` and `60` are integers, so `(10 / 60)` results in an integer answer -- `0`.

If one of them is a double literal, e.g. `10.0` (or equivalently, `10d` or `(double)10`), you get a double result -- `0.166666`.

Example fix:

```
ExamPerc = (ExamDoub / (10.0 / 60));
```

Comment: Correct. But I would add that note: `ExamDoub / (10 / 60) = ExamDoub / (1 / 6) = ExamDoub * 6`. This division is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. :) Something so simple that I couldn't see. How do I get it to show as a percentage with 2 decimal places? It's only appearing as 1 decimal place.